# Invalid argument

Tags: php, foreach

EDIT: Is it because of $i being initialised to 1 and not 0...???

I store certain values that I retrieve from the database in a session variable. This is how I do that:

```
$i = 1;   
//query to select tuples from the database;
while($i <= $num) //$num is the count of the rows returned by the query
{
    $_SESSION['first'][$i] = $row->first;
    $_SESSION['second'][$i] = $row->second;
    $i++;
}
```

I then use them as follows:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($_SESSION['first'] as $names)
{
    //do something with $_SESSION['second'][$i];
    $i++;
}
```

**The error I get:**
(which disappears once I refresh the page)

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Do you verify that `$_SESSION['first']` is an array before calling the `foreach`?

Comment: Yes. I used: print_var ($_SESSION['first']); //displays array with index 1 = Somevalue.

Comment: What about when the error appears?

Comment: Obvious solutions first: are you definitely running `session_start()`?

Comment: @Matt: The functionality is not disturbed. Just the error pops up.

Comment: If `$_SESSION['first']` were an array, the error wouldn't appear.

Comment: @vgkuttu - This error is caused by the first argument to `foreach` not being an array. WHY the value isn't an array when you're expecting it to be is the problem; the bottom line is that the error is thrown only in one circumstance. (edit: as Matt said)

Comment: On using print_var ($_SESSION['names']); , I get: Array ( [1] => userABBSD )

Comment: If you get that output every time, then you wouldn't get the error you're describing, it's just that simple. `$_SESSION['names']` is not an array when you pass it to `foreach`, that's why it throws the error.

Comment: @vgkuttu "EDIT: Is it because of $i being initialised to 1 and not 0...???" -- No.

Comment: But why does it disappear on refresh. Any change in session?

Comment: @vgkuttu Without seeing the entire script, it is hard to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the variable is an array before looping with `is_array`:

```
$i = 1;
if (is_array($_SESSION['first'])) { foreach ($_SESSION['first'] as $names) {
    //do something with $_SESSION['second'][$i];
    $i++;
}}
```

The problem may come from the way you're initially placing values into the array, which can easily be corrected with `is_array`

```
$i = 1;
if (!is_array($_SESSION['first']))
    $_SESSION['first'] = array();
//query to select tuples from the database;
while($i <= $num) //$num is the count of the rows returned by the query
{
    $_SESSION['first'][$i] = $row->first;
    $_SESSION['second'][$i] = $row->second;
    $i++;
}
```

**Documentation**

- `is_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php
- `foreach` - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not possible. The error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` indicates that an array was not passed to `foreach`. If you were passing it an array, it wouldn't throw that error. Either you're not checking that it is an array, or the error is not coming from the code you've put in your question.

Comment: The problem is not with lack of `$_SESSION['first']` but rather with lack of `$_SESSION` at all.

Comment: Maybe, not enough detail to determine that. One call to `session_start` changes everything.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, when `$num == 0` your `$_SESSION` will never be intialized, so `$_SESSION['first']` will not exist.

Comment: $num will definitely be greater than 0.

Comment: Dear vgkuttu. I bet $num is less or equal 0. I will be very, very much surprized if not. If you put the whole code in `if ( $num > 0 )...` it should disappear. Note - I put on stake my php knowledge ;)

Comment: You might be right. But, I can definitely guarantee you that $num will at the least be 1.

Comment: Dear vgkuttu. I cannot be right if `$num` is > 0 and the error is shown. Unless there is something more that happens between these two blocks of the code you showed to us. The best way is, if you add this `if ( $num > 0 )` in front of the `foreach`. If you see the error then the `$_SESSION` is deleted before reaching the `foreach` loop.